# Can gems have circular dependencies?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, dependencies, dependency-management, circular-dependency

I've developed a small gem ecosystem and certain features will result in them depending on each other.

Does RubyGems support circular dependencies? In other words, is it safe to push gems with these specifications?

```
Gem::Specification.new 'essentials' do |gem|
  gem.add_development_dependency 'development_tools'
end

Gem::Specification.new 'development_tools' do |gem|
  gem.add_runtime_dependency 'essentials'
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not have circular **runtime** dependencies.

It should be OK, if weird, for one gem to have a **development** dependency on another gem which has a **runtime** dependency on the first.

Nevertheless, I would **not** recommend it. I would recommend ensuring that your dependencies graph is completely empty of cycles.

Comment: Please, can you provide more details? What are the problems that could arise? Are they specific to RubyGems?

Comment: Cyclical dependencies are, in general, to be avoided. There are many important things that we need to do with dependency graphs that we cannot do if the graphs have cycles. One example of an important thing we need to do is: to sort the dependency graphs: but a directed graph with cycles cannot be sorted.

Comment: What kind of answer is this? The question was if RubyGems supports circular dependencies, not if @yfeldblum recommends them.

Comment: @ggPeti this is a perfectly fine answer. The explicitly asked question is answered explicitly, and the implicitly asked question is also answered. Addressing implicit questions with sound advice is a good practice I think, not something we want to discourage. Anyway, the question I'm calling "implicit" is actually also explicitly asked when OP puts in his question "is it safe to push gems with these specifications" in which  "safe" can imply many different types of safety: safe from errors, safe from bad design, safe from future changes.

Answer (score 3):

That's not technically a circular dependency, since each dependency is of a different kind.  If it were a true circular dependency I would be recommending combining both into one gem, but your gem names illustrate the intent, which is sane.

It should work just fine.